# git svn rebase while others work on my files

Tags: git, git-svn

I am new to git and I am trying to work with it against my SVN server.
I don't understand the reason to "git svn rebase" to get updated. From what I understand, if I update my local repository with the SVN server, commit to GIT (locally) my changes, and than "git svn rebase", I might overwrite other users changes on the files I work on.

Do I understand correctly? and if I do, why would I want to use rebase and take such risk (I understand the idea of fast forward, but it sounds really risky)?

Hope I am not missing something basic!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The opposite is true: `git svn rebase` prevents you from overwriting others' work. As the [Git-SCM book](http://git-scm.com/docs/git-svn) aptly notes, think of `git svn rebase` as your equivalent of `svn update`. It is the *way you update your local repository with the SVN server*.

#### In a standard SVN workflow...

...you check out a repository version (let's say, @9001). You make some changes, and are ready to commit, but—oops—someone checked in change 9002. You `svn update` to revision 9002, merge if necessary, and then check in your change to produce 9003. If you hadn't run `svn update`, you would overwrite your teammate's revision 9002; by running `svn update` you're *acting as though you based your work on revision 9002 and not 9001*.

```
SVN         9001-------------------------------9002---------------9003--------->
                \                                  \             / svn commit
your feature     local work       [now update]      updated work
```

#### In a standard git workflow...

...history isn't numbered and linear. You can commit whenever you want, locally, and merge your work into whichever commit your team designates the "master" branch.

```
your teammate's feature            T1--T2--T3---T4--T5
                                  /                   \  merge
master      M1------------------M2-------M3------------M4--------M5------------->
                                           \                    / merge
your feature                                Y1-----Y2-----Y3--Y4
```

I've labeled Y1 Y2 Y3 Y4 as *your local commits of your feature work*, all based on the state of the world you checked out *M3*. All of this history is public, so if you were to commit just like the above, your teammates could tell you based Y1 off of M3. If you wanted to *change that*, you could ask git to base your feature work off of M4 instead. That's known as a *git rebase*.

```
your teammate's feature            T1--T2--T3---T4--T5
                                  /                   \  merge
master      M1------------------M2-------M3------------M4----------------M5----->
                                                         \              / merge
your feature after rebase                                 Y1--Y2--Y3--Y4
```

After the rebase, all of the commit IDs (hashes) change, because they're computed based on the parents of your commit and by rebasing you deliberately change the parents.

#### So in your git+svn workflow...

...you need to *map git's commit graph onto svn's linear history*. This means running an `svn update` (`git svn rebase`) before you commit in order to base your work off of the latest revision in the SVN repository.

```
SVN         9001-------------------------------9002----------------9003--------->
                \                                  \              / git svn dcommit
your feature     Y1--Y2--Y3--Y4   [now rebase]      Y1--Y2--Y3--Y4
```

See the [Git-SCM chapter on SVN](https://git-scm.com/book/en/v1/Git-and-Other-Systems-Git-and-Subversion) for more explanation and examples.